# Add table row dynamically with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables, row

I am having difficulty to add new table row with JSON.

**Situation**

Currently I am programming drag & drop function. Once file uploaded, file information parse into JSON and return to the View page. What I want is that I want to add new table row dynamically with JSON file information.

**Problem**
How should I fill in the double quotes part with JSON format?

```js
var rowNode = table.row.add( [
            "",
            "",
            "[what should i write here??]",
            "[what should i write here??]",
            "<td id=wtax_file_type></td>",
            "<td id=all_tax></td>",
            "<td id=tax_date></td>",
            "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default'><i class='icon-file-pdf text-error'></i><span> 테스트.pdf</span></button>",
            "<a class='btn-link color-primary'>[이동]</a>"
        ] ).draw().node();
```

**My JS code**

```js
myDropzone.on("success", function(file, res) {


        /* removew preview when upload success*/
        $(file.previewElement).remove();

        console.log(res);

        if (res.result) {
            if (res.data) {
                if (res.data.f_idx) {
                    $('#f_idx').text(res.data.f_idx);
                }
                if (res.data.client_name) {
                    $('#client_name').text(res.data.client_name);
                }
                if (res.data.client_biz_no) {
                    $('#client_biz_no').text(res.data.client_biz_no);
                }
                if (res.data.wtax_file_type) {
                    $('#wtax_file_type').text(res.data.wtax_file_type);
                }
                if (res.data.all_tax) {
                    $('#all_tax').text(res.data.all_tax);
                }
                if (res.data.tax_date) {
                    $('#tax_date').text(res.data.tax_date);
                }
            }
        }

        var fileObj=JSON.parse(res);


       var rowNode = table.row.add( [
            "",
            "",
            "[what should i write here??]",
            "what should i write here??]",
            "<td id=wtax_file_type></td>",
            "<td id=all_tax></td>",
            "<td id=tax_date></td>",
            "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default'><i class='icon-file-pdf text-error'></i><span> 테스트.pdf</span></button>",
            "<a class='btn-link color-primary'>[이동]</a>"
        ] ).draw().node();


    });
```

Comment: Looks like datatables code. Is it?

Comment: You need to add a new row that conatins 5 cells where the las t two contains a `button` and a `link` ?

Comment: @SebastienD Yes I think so. I want to add new table row with file information after upload successfully. But i dont know how to use JSON object in javascript.

this is sample image of my data table(https://ibb.co/hssqYH)

Comment: You should add the `datatables` tag to your question then

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui I want to add row which contains 9 cells. Last two cells are download link and button. This is the sample table image what i am working now 

image url : https://ibb.co/hssqYH

Comment: This page gives you a good example on how it works: https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

Comment: @SebastienD I will try to search with datatable tags. thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to [datatable's documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html), this could be done like this:

```
table.row.add( [
        "",
        "",
        "[what should i write here??]",
        "[what should i write here??]",
        $('#wtax_file_type').text(),
        $('#all_tax').text(),
        $('#tax_date').text(),
        "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default'><i class='icon-file-pdf text-error'></i><span> 테스트.pdf</span></button>",
        "<a class='btn-link color-primary'>[이동]</a>"
    ] ).draw( false );
```